# Is there any connection between the Vandenreich and the Bounto?

Tags: bleach

In Bleach, both the Vandenreich (the Quincy group that is attacking the Soul Society) and the Bounto use German in their names. In Bleach, in general, different groups use different languages, such as the Hollows using Spanish and the Bounto using German, but this is the first time (that I can think of) that there is a repeat. Is there a connection, or is it something that can be dismissed because the Bounto only appeared in anime filler?

Comment: by the way, the quincy always used German

Answer (score 2):

The Bounto saga was only a filler, so I think the main history will never comment about them again.

By the way, I think there is no clearly evidence of a relation between German and the Bounts, like their names, abilities.....

Yes, I think you can dismiss it :)

Comment: The setting was german and so were their incantations